# Add columns to a pivot table (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I know in R I can use tidyr for the following:

```
data_wide <- spread(data_protein, Fraction, Count)
```

and data_wide will inherit all the columns from data_protein that are not spread.

```
Protein Peptide  Start  Fraction  Count
1             A    122       F1     1
1             A    122       F2     2     
1             B    230       F1     3     
1             B    230       F2     4
```

becomes

```
Protein Peptide  Start  F1  F2
1             A    122   1  2
1             B    230   3  4
```

But in pandas (Python),

```
data_wide = data_prot2.reset_index(drop=True).pivot('Peptide','Fraction','Count').fillna(0)
```

doesn't inherit anything not specified in the function (index, key, value).
Thus, I decided to join it through df.join():

```
data_wide2 = data_wide.join(data_prot2.set_index('Peptide')['Start']).sort_values('Start')
```

But that produces duplicates of the peptides because there are several start values. Is there any more straightforward way to solve this? Or a special parameter for join that omits repeats? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
In [144]: df
Out[144]:
   Protein Peptide  Start Fraction  Count
0        1       A    122       F1      1
1        1       A    122       F2      2
2        1       B    230       F1      3
3        1       B    230       F2      4

In [145]: df.pivot_table(index=['Protein','Peptide','Start'], columns='Fraction').reset_index()
Out[145]:
         Protein Peptide Start Count
Fraction                          F1 F2
0              1       A   122     1  2
1              1       B   230     3  4
```

you can also specify `Count` column explicitly:

```
In [146]: df.pivot_table(index=['Protein','Peptide','Start'], columns='Fraction', values='Count').reset_index()
Out[146]:
Fraction  Protein Peptide  Start  F1  F2
0               1       A    122   1   2
1               1       B    230   3   4
```

Comment: In what step do I do this? When do I specify that Count is the value for Fraction?

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack`:

```
df.set_index(df.columns[:4].tolist()) \
  .Count.unstack().reset_index() \
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`spread` is superseded by `pivot_wider` in `tidyr`.

How about using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) that follows `tidyr`'s API design:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, pivot_wider
>>> data_protein = tribble(
...     f.Protein, f.Peptide,  f.Start,  f.Fraction,  f.Count,
...     1,         "A",        122,      "F1",        1,
...     1,         "A",        122,      "F2",        2,     
...     1,         "B",        230,      "F1",        3,     
...     1,         "B",        230,      "F2",        4,
... )
>>> data_wide = pivot_wider(data_protein, names_from=f.Fraction, values_from=f.Count)
>>> data_wide
  Peptide  Protein  Start  F1  F2
0       A        1    122   1   2
1       B        1    230   3   4
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.